# How to build a custom environment in Grails

Tags: grails

I'm trying to add a new environment to our Grails WAR (let's call it "staging").  I can manage the configuration in Config.groovy and DataSource.groovy and access the right configuration at run-time with -Dgrails.env, but how do I build this WAR?

The [Grails documentation](https://grails.org/wiki/Environments) does not cover this case and the links on the page seem to be outdated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are so very close to having the right combination in your question, this should work:

```
grails -Dgrails.env=staging war
```

Actually, the [documentation](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.x/ref/Command%20Line/war.html) for the `war` command even uses 'staging' as the environment used.

The same goes for any environment-specific command:

```
grails -Dgrails.env=<environment name> <command>
```